# Is it possible to integrate Ink toolbar (UWP) to window form c#

Tags: c#, winforms, uwp

I am new on to develop window base application, I just wondering is it possible to integrate Ink toolbar (That use in Universal Windows Platform) use in traditional window form (The Surface pen able to write and saved as image)

Thank you

Comment: It's available in UWP apps only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it possible to integrate Ink toolbar (That use in Universal Windows Platform) use in traditional window form (The Surface pen able to write and saved as image)

It's not possible in traditional Win32/Winform application, why not consider of migrating to UWP?:)

BTW, you may be interest in [Convert your desktop application to a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root)